# Use eas-cli to set up Android Keystore non-interactively from command line?

Tags: expo

Is it possible to use `eas-cli` to set up the Android keystore for a project non-interactively from the command line?

Adding `-non-interactive` to `eas build --platform android` fails if I haven't previously interactively set up the Android keystore.

e.g. I want some command like `eas build --platform android --non-interactive --initialize-keystore` or `eas credentials --non-interactive --initialize-keystore`

(For context: for a project I'm working on, I want to be able to create and build new Expo  automatically)

Answer (score 0):

You should run this process one time for Android in interactive mode and after you see a question about creating a keystore answer it yes.

`npm install -g eas-cli expo-cli`

`eas-cli build --platform=android --profile=test`

After that, you can run it in non-interactive mode.

`eas-cli build --platform all --profile test --non-interactive --no-wait`